# .net 3.5 windows form application, using webcam

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, webcam

Having searched high and low for native c# hook to webcam, I found 5 basic ways to interact with the camera.

1. Video for Windows (VFW)
2. DirectX
3. `avicap32.dll`
4. WIA
5. 3rd party tools

My requirement is to take a photo.  The application will be used on some legacy windows XP and Vista machines, but going forward Windows 7 and greater will be required.  So what might the best approach be with the broad install base?  Just reading WIA looked like the way to go but looks like some changes were made so it works a little different now (I don't know for sure).  I understand that some people have done combos.

Might need to crop photo, but that is really about it.

For school visitor monitoring.

Comment: Looking for feed back on what issues people have ran into.  I see several positives to all of them and not sure what negatives might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best thing is to use the WIA. I know a third party toolkit that could help you doing your requirements which is leadtools. You can check this [Tutorial](http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v175/dh/to/leadtools.topics.wia~wa.topics.wiaacquiringanimage.html)

Comment: Third party is really a last resort.  What is great about wia?

Comment: Company bought leadtools for another project so will probably go that direction.

Answer (score 1):

I would always try to pick up something already on the web and tweak it to my own needs... some open source project or an example where the mainly portion of my app is already made.

on Codeplex you can find a nice library to work with webcams and it's simply called

> [WebCam Library for WinForm and WPF with C# and VB.NET](http://easywebcam.codeplex.com/)

Give that a try, maybe you can even help the project, by contributing your own findings, and everyone is a winner... isn't Open Source a great idea?!

Comment: I had looked at the project.  It wasn't really what I was hoping for.

Comment: this is just one, like this one, there are dozens. **My point was**, pick something already in the market and tweak it to your needs, no need to do everything from scratch.

Comment: balexandre - there are dozens and I have looked at many of them.  Not planing on doing anything from scratch.  You might have noticed that I was asking for what others might suggest as best solution.  The one you linked to hide all the camera calls in a dll that it didn't have much documented. I was hoping for someone that had actually tried one of the solutions that could say, yeah I used xx and it works except for x issue.