# webcam, Video Source dialog comes up

Tags: windows, winforms, video, camera, webcam

So have seen a ton of people with the same issue's but no answers.  My SendMessage pop's up the "Video Source" dialog box on a windows 7 laptop with one camera.  I have Cyber Link YouCam installed.
[image: 'Video Source' dialog box]

If I uninstall Cyber Link YouCam the "Video Source" dialog goes away.  It appears to be the OS is acting as though YouCam is a second driver for the same device.  My question is how do I stop the dialog box for "Video Source" from appearing?  Once I choose an option in the dialog I don't get the dialog box (until I restart the application) so there must be a setting somewhere being set.

Though debugging found this bit of code (see whole section below) is the one that seems to be the one that calls the dialog box - SendMessage (deviceHandle, WM_CAP_CONNECT, deviceno, ((IntPtr) 0).ToInt32 ())

```
 public void StartWebCam (int height, int width, int handleofthepicturebox, int deviceno)
        {

        string deviceIndex = "" + deviceno;

        deviceHandle = capCreateCaptureWindowA (ref deviceIndex, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 0, 0, width, height, handleofthepicturebox, 0);


        if (SendMessage (deviceHandle, WM_CAP_CONNECT, deviceno, ((IntPtr) 0).ToInt32 ()) > 0)
            {


            SendMessage (deviceHandle, WM_CAP_SET_SCALE, -1, 0);
            SendMessage (deviceHandle, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE, 0x42, 0);
            SendMessage (deviceHandle, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, -1, 0);

            }
        else
            {
            // nothing failed maybe some clean up needed
            }

        }
```

So again the question is -   how do I stop the dialog box for "Video Source" from appearing?

Comment: Use more recent video capture APIs in Windows: DirectShow or Media Foundation. VFW you are using was deprecated long ago and it seems that YouCam is hooking it in some bad way to force the dialog popup.

Comment: Thanks Roman R.  I can't seem to find a lot of C# or .net information on Media Foundation.

Comment: I had created a question [Web Cam and c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591036/net-3-5-windows-form-application-using-webcam) about what direction I should take.

Comment: On that Q you indicate you want support of Windows XP. Media Foundation is not going to work well for you then, so DirectShow is the best you can have for streaming video. Perhaps WIA for taking stills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I developed a form to display two live captures with avicap32 on Windows XP. There is a chance the fix I found in my case also applies to yours.

In the case of avicap, it is possible to programmatically manage your webcams, and all that is registry-based. Here is [the thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/c4fd12d8-2870-47ed-8f2e-3dc613afeb6f/) I found to guide me and achieve what I wanted.

In this thread, the role of the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\MediaResources\msvideo\MSVideo.VFWWDM\DevicePath` registry key is highlighted for the selection of the active webcam.

And here is maybe a helpful piece of info: I had to set the value in lowercase to avoid the Video Source dialog popping up.

I determined it by monitoring the registry key before and after the call to `SendMessage` with `WM_CAP_CONNECT`.

To the best of my knowledge (and googling), nobody else has offered a fix, so even though I might be answering a little late, it would be great if you could tell us whether it worked for you as well.

Comment: It's not to late, still working on the project.  Will look at your answer closer in a few weeks.

Comment: I am no longer working on this project so didn't get to try the solution.  So I don't know if it answered the question.  Gave it a plus 1 though

Answer (score 1):

Finally I Found a solution for this.
The problem happens in Windows 7 / 8

First you need this API function

```
Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
```

Then... after you call `capCreateCaptureWindowA()` you have to wait 1 second processing events, (note: sleep don't work the same)

```
IniTime = GetTickCount()
While GetTickCount() < (IniTime + 1000)
   DoEvents
Wend
```

then you call `WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT` (maybe a couple of times).. and THAT's IT ... no more video source dialog

Answer (score 1):

With this solution it works perfect. The `GetTickCount()` waiting for events worked along with calling the function until it returned true.

```
Private Sub PreviewVideo(ByVal pbCtrl As PictureBox)    
    hWnd = capCreateCaptureWindowA(VideoSource, WS_VISIBLE Or WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 0,
   0, pbCtrl.Handle.ToInt64, 0)    
    Dim IniTime As Long = GetTickCount() 
    While GetTickCount() < (IniTime + 1000)
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While    
    Dim OKAnswer As Boolean = False
    For xretries As Integer = 1 To 10
          ' I'll give you Only 10 tries to connect, otherwise I AM LEAVING MICROSOFT!
          OKAnswer = SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, VideoSource, 0)
          If OKAnswer Then
              Exit For
          End If    
    Next    
    If okanswer Then
          SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CAP_SET_SCALE, True, 0)
          SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE, 30, 0)
          SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, True, 0)
          SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, pbCtrl.Width, pbCtrl.Height, SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOZORDER)    
    Else
          DestroyWindow(hWnd)    
    End If    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Make sure you call capDriverDisconnect once you no longer need the webcam. Note that I'm using Logitech C110, but I suppose it should work in your case too.

Answer (score 0):

Came over here searching for a solution for the "WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT" and "Video Setup" dialog popup Error.

FOUND the solution:

It's a driver problem. Use the OEM's driver, because the Generic Microsoft Drivers are NOT working for your camera.

Use www.astra32.com to find out the USB camera's device info: Manufacturer or Model; then google for the correct drivers.

Good Luck!