# C# simplest way to capture an image from webcam without video source dialog

Tags: c#, webcam

What is the simplest way to capture an image from the webcam without showing a dialog asking the user to confirm the source of the video capture?

I don't want to use any third party libraries.

I've read several answers, like that one, but nothing worked for me: [webcam, Video Source dialog comes up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721085/webcam-video-source-dialog-comes-up)

Here is my current source code:

```
static object GetFrame()
    {
        int mCapHwnd = capCreateCaptureWindowA("WebCap", 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle.ToInt32(), 0);

        // connect to the capture device
        SendMessage(mCapHwnd, WM_CAP_CONNECT, 0, 0);

        // get the next frame
        SendMessage(mCapHwnd, WM_CAP_GET_FRAME, 0, 0);

        // copy the frame to the clipboard
        SendMessage(mCapHwnd, WM_CAP_COPY, 0, 0);

        // disconnect the capture device
        SendMessage(mCapHwnd, WM_CAP_DISCONNECT, 0, 0);

        return Clipboard.GetDataObject();
    }
```

Comment: Look at [this SO question and solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721085/webcam-video-source-dialog-comes-up)